# Zephyr adding Testcases to a Test Cycle via REST API

Tags: jira-zephyr

I've been reviewing the API documentation for Zephyr Scale (https://support.smartbear.com/zephyr-scale-cloud/api-docs/#tag/Test-Cycles) and I've noticed that the documentation doesn't outline how to add a test case to a test cycle.

Since test cycles are groups of test cases (as per Zephyr documentation https://support.smartbear.com/zephyr-scale-cloud/docs/en/test-plans/test-plans--overview-.html) Using the API to create test cycles and then having to use the UI to add test cases seems like something very basic is missing... so clearly I'm missing something.

Anyone got a pointer for me